# Colunas invisíveis no Listview

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

Tenho um *listview* com uma série de colunas, mas gostaria de ocultar algumas, como faço isso?

Comment: WPF? Win Forms? Web Forms?

Comment: Ana, resolveu seu problema ?

Comment: Olá @RovannLinhalis sim consegui! Obrigada a todos pela ajuda :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ao que me parece o `ListView` trabalha de forma semelhante ao `TabControl`, onde não é possível definir uma propriedade `Visible`.

Entretanto quando você adiciona uma coluna ao `ListView`, ela também é um objeto dentro do seu Form, que pode ser acessado pelo nome definido a ela.

No exemplo, utilizei um `listView` e adicionei 3 colunas, em seguida eu removo e adiciono a coluna de nome `columnHeader2`:

```
//Removendo
if (listView1.Columns.Contains(columnHeader2))
    listView1.Columns.Remove(columnHeader2);

//Adicionando
if (!listView1.Columns.Contains(columnHeader2))
{
    listView1.Columns.Add(columnHeader2);
    //Defino a posição dela novamente, caso contrário ela estará na última coluna.
    columnHeader2.DisplayIndex = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Acho que só definindo a coluna como Width igual a 0, o que vai ocultá-la.

```
seuListView.Columns[indiceDaColuna].Width = 0;
```